# add_menu_page item show to Editor Role Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, menuitem, roles, capability

I've been trying to add a menu to my WP Dashboard which I already accomplished. But now I want to show this menu to the Editor role as well as the administrator.

Here is my code

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );
function register_my_custom_menu_page() { 
 add_menu_page( 'Instagram test', 'Instagram test', 'read', 'admin.php?page=sb-instagram-feed', '', 'dashicons-welcome-widgets-menus', 90 );
}
```

So far it works, but only for my administrator user, not to my Editors users.

I've read about the capabilities and that is why I put the `read` value on the function above.

How can I also show this menu to my Editors users?

Here is a screenshot, my custom menu is *Instagram test*.

Admin's Dashboard

[image]

Editor's Dashboard

[image: Editors Dashboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't attest to *why* `read` isn't working - generally if you want to limit something by user roles, you can put in the slug for the role. If you read the source for [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) it will actually run the capability through [`current_user_can`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) which accepts a role slug as well.

I would replace `read` with `editor` and see what that gets you. It will also work for admins since it propagates down the list and `administrators` all have the `editor`, `contributor`, etc. "capabilities".

**Edit**: It appears you have the [Instagram Feed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/instagram-feed/) plugin installed which will be conflicting with your custom plugin. The code from that plugin shows the `sb-instagram-feed` page belongs to that plugin:

```
function sb_instagram_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        __( 'Instagram Feed', 'instagram-feed' ),
        __( 'Instagram Feed', 'instagram-feed' ),
        'manage_options',
        'sb-instagram-feed',
        'sb_instagram_settings_page'
    );
    add_submenu_page(
        'sb-instagram-feed',
        __( 'Settings', 'instagram-feed' ),
        __( 'Settings', 'instagram-feed' ),
        'manage_options',
        'sb-instagram-feed',
        'sb_instagram_settings_page'
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'sb_instagram_menu');
```

And that plugin requires `manage_options`, an `administrator` only capability. You'll need to not link to the page that other plugin makes, or deactivate that plugin.

**Edit 2**: Note that editing plugin files directly usually isn't a great practice as any changes you make will be overwritten when the plugin is updated. You *might* be able to unhook the current admin menu for it and hook in your custom one.

```
// Remove Existing Menu
remove_action( 'admin_menu', 'sb_instagram_menu' );

// Add Custom Menu
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_sb_instagram_menu');
function custom_sb_instagram_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Instagram Test',
        'Instagram Test',
        'editor',
        'sb-instagram-feed',
        'sb_instagram_settings_page'
    );
    add_submenu_page(
        'sb-instagram-feed',
        'Test Settings',
        'Test Settings',
        'editor',
        'sb-instagram-feed',
        'sb_instagram_settings_page'
    );
}
```

Comment: thank u for ur suggestions. I tried changing from administrator to editor but did not worked. Also i checked the current_user_can but did not do anything. 
if (current_user_can('editor')) { my code } i really wonder why it only shows on my admin and not the rest of Editors

Comment: Instead of **editor** i used **edit_pages** and it worked. But when i go to that menu it shows me: *Sorry,youarenotallowed*

Comment: Updated the answer, you have a conflict with the Instagram Feed plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the feeback! i see that. well i can't deactivate because i want to show that plugin. 
What im trying to do is just showing that menu (instagram) to my **Editor** user.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! i changed that section on the code u just uploaded: **manage_options** to **edit_pages** and now the editor can go to that plugin. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Just a note, if you update a plugin file like that - any changes you make will be overwritten when you update the plugin! I've provided another edit, you may be able to unhook the current one, but it may take some finagling

Comment: i have a child theme, there i put my functions.php file. Thanks for the new code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct one for Admin and Editor role both.

```
add_menu_page( 'Transcoding Mp3', 'Transcoding Mp3', 'edit_pages', 'transcoding_mp3', 'transcoding_mp3_fun',  '',  90 );
function transcoding_mp3_fun() {    
 $currentusr = wp_get_current_user();
 $idcur = $currentusr->data->ID;
 $namecur = $currentusr->data->user_login;
 echo 'This is editor id = '. $namecur;          
}
```